# Can you use pandas/python to concatenate a folder of .xlsx files based on row 2?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I'm having trouble using pandas to concatenate a very large folder of .xlsx files. The issue is we have some text written in the first row of each document that can't be removed.

My path to the folder is set and the concatenate works. The issue is after the first file, it's removing the ID #'s in the first 2 columns when concatenating the rest of the files. So not only does the data not match going down each column, but I also have lost my unique identifiers. My best guess is this is due to the 1st row of text in each document.

This is what I have so far.

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.xlsx')]

iep_boy_df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, f), sheetname='Academic Outlier List', encoding='utf-8') for f in files],
               keys=files, names=['File Name', 'Row']).reset_index()
```

I've seen some ways to parse files using Python, but can you parse 50+ excel documents to skip row 1 and then pass them into pandas to concat into a DF? All in all I want row 1 to be excluded when concatenating.

Still an intermediate here with Python so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried `pd.read_excel(skiprows=[0])`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will completely solve your import problems, but Pandas `read_excel()` has a `skipped_rows` parameter that you could pass to skip the first row. Note that its type is a zero-indexed list.

Reference: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Upvoted you, but I'm new so it says it won't count.

That worked splendidly! I had been looking at the Pandas documentation for concatenate and couldn't figure this out. The only weird thing is it moved a couple columns to the end, but I think this might be because some of the people hid the columns with the ID numbers. Either way that's an easy fix for me. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would echo piRSQUARED's answer. pd.read_excel has skiprows but remember to pass skip rows as an iterable.

Comment: Worked great! Thank you for the help, did need to make sure skiprows=1 goes in the right spot.